# RabbitMQ - how to restart node from cluster without need of sync of queues?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ cluster with 2 nodes. I have set HA policy to sync all queues across all nodes. Let's assume, that I have 2 nodes: A and B. A is master, B has all queues synchronised from A.

Now I want to restart server with node B (to upgrade server, OS, etc.). No matter what I do, always, after restart, full sync process is needed to have these queues synchronised between A and B. Even, if I stop all consumers and producers before process of restarting. It hurts if queues have a lot of messages.

**Question: is there any way to make "clean shutdown" to ommit queues sync process after restart?**

Comment: Perhaps you have your queues set up to sync automatically? See "ha-sync-mode" here https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

Comment: I have same question, how to restart node in 3 node cluster?